# How to deploy Simple Java Spring boot application into Azure Web Job?

Tags: spring-boot, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-webjobssdk

I have a simple spring boot application with controller class having Rest API's. Now I want to deploy this Java Spring application into Azure Web Job and trigger manually.

In Microsoft documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create) the details of deploying application written in .NET and C# is provided but I could not find anything related to Java or Spring boot App deployment into Azure Web job.

Can anyone please let me know the steps to be followed for deploying Spring boot app into Azure Web Job or Attach any documentations for reference?

Thanks & Regards,
Preethi H R

Answer (score 1):

To execute the Java web jobs on Azure, I have followed the [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/azureossds/executing-java-web-jobs-on-azure).

1. created a Java spring boot Project and compressed into zip file.
2. Open Azure Portal, navigate to **App Service** page of your App Service web app and select Webjobs and add a new Webjob by providing required settings as specified below:
3. On the **WebJobs** page, select **Add**.
4. Fill the details in **Add WebJob** settings as specified in the table.
   [image]

- **File Upload**: Upload Executable or script file which has been converted to zip file (Springboot_H2_database_CRUD.zip).

Create a manually triggered WebJob

1. select **WebJobs** in Azure App service, create a new web job by selecting **Type** as **Triggered** in the settings and select **Manual** in Triggers.

[image]

2. Select **OK**.
3. To run the WebJob, click on the webjob name and select **Run**.
   [image]

**Create a scheduled WebJob**

> - A scheduled Webjob is also triggered. You can schedule the trigger to occur automatically on the schedule you specify.

[image]

- Select **OK** and **Run** the newly created webjob.

[image]

- Desired execution frequency can be configured for the web job.

Comment: Hi Pravallika, Thank you for your detailed answer, It is helpful. I have tried to add batch file inside my project folder and tried to deploy the web job. But then I am getting the following errors in web job logs when I run the web job:

Comment: [11/21/2022 10:39:10 > c96804: INFO] [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources (default-resources) on project testProject: Execution default-resources of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0:resources failed: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:3.2.0 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.sonatype.sisu:sisu-guice:jar:no_aop:3.1.0, aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0, org.eclipse.sisu:org.eclipse.sisu.inject:jar:0.0.0.M2a, asm:asm:jar:3.3.1,

Comment: Modify the version of Maven resources plugin in `pom.xml` as shown in this [DOC](https://debugah.com/solved-failed-to-execute-goal-org-apache-maven-pluginsmaven-resources-plugin3-2-0-22975/)

Comment: Hi Pravallika, Even after adding the plugin as specified in the doc I am getting the following error

Comment: INFO] [ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.4.3: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.4.3 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2):